# SQL Server SUM is returning null, it should return 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query returns null if the columns are empty. It should return 0 so I can compute it inside my codes.

I've search through the web and found the "COALESCE" and "ISNULL" I am using SQL Server 2012 what should I use? and I tried the ISNULL and its not working in my query. This is my code.

```
 SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(SUM (Male) as Male, SUM(Female) as Female ,SUM(Pax) as Pax,SUM(Single) as Single,SUM(Married) as Married,SUM(Students) as Students,SUM(Elementary) as Elementary,SUM(Highschool) as Highschool,SUM(College) as College,SUM(PWD) as PWD, SUM([AR Users]) as ARUsers,SUM([12 Below]) as age1,SUM([13-21]) as age2,SUM([22-35]) as age3,SUM([36-50]) as age4,SUM([51-65]) as age5,SUM([65 Above]) as age6 ,0) FROM  [tbl_ForeignVisit] where [Date Added] >= '"
            + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "' AND  [Date Added] <='" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "'  ;", connection);
```

Comment: Some sample data would help to show others what your query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: You should (must!) use parameters rather than string concatenation. The above code will not work if the SQL Server has a different date format to the machine running the code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection shows you how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use **ISNULL** for each SUM colunms.

Ex.  `ISNULL(SUM(Male),0) as Male`

Return: 0

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` for each `SUM` colunms instead of only one.

and your SQL query string have SQL injection problem, please use parameters instead of Connect SQL syntax

```
string sqlQuery = @"SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(Male),0) as Male, 
    ISNULL(SUM(Female),0)  as Female ,
    ISNULL(SUM(Pax),0)  as Pax,
    ISNULL(SUM(Single),0)  as Single,
    ISNULL(SUM(Married),0)  as Married,
    ISNULL(SUM(Students),0)  as Students,
    ISNULL(SUM(Elementary),0)  as Elementary,
    ISNULL(SUM(Highschool),0)  as Highschool,
    ISNULL(SUM(College),0)  as College,
    ISNULL(SUM(PWD),0)  as PWD, 
    ISNULL(SUM([AR Users]),0)  as ARUsers,
    ISNULL(SUM([12 Below]),0)  as age1,
    ISNULL(SUM([13-21]),0)  as age2,
    ISNULL(SUM([22-35]),0)  as age3,
    ISNULL(SUM([36-50]),0)  as age4,
    ISNULL(SUM([51-65]),0)  as age5,
    ISNULL(SUM([65 Above]),0)  as age6
FROM  [tbl_ForeignVisit] 
where [Date Added] >= @DateAdded"

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery);
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@DateAdded", SqlDbType.Date);
cmd2.Parameters["@DateAdded"].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
```

**Note**

If you want to get data by compare `date` type. I would set  `SqlDbType.Date` in parameter to make sure the `date` type can be compare.

Comment: This answer is just straight to the point. Thank you very much

Comment: @Kcird No problem gald to help:)

Comment: @kcird you can saw my edit answer more explain for you

Comment: @Kcird using parameter that can easier avoid SQL injection. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: You can saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements